# jqLite - .triggerHanlder() behavior not working as expected

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have a piece of code using `triggerHandler` that is calling the correct event, but the event isn't working. Here is the code and a jsFiddle :

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="app">
    <button box-creator>Button</button>
</body>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.directive("boxCreator", function($document, $compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            $element.bind("mousedown", function($event) {
                var newNode = $compile('<div class="box" drag></div>')($scope);

                newNode.css({
                    top: $event.pageY - 25 + "px",
                    left: $event.pageX - 25 + "px"
                    });

                angular.element($document[0].body).append(newNode);
                angular.element(newNode).triggerHandler("mousedown"); // This line is called
            });
        }
    }
});

app.directive("drag", function($document) {
    return function(scope, element, attr) {
        var startX = 0, startY = 0, x = event.pageX - 25, y = event.pageY - 25;

        element.css({
         position: 'absolute',
         cursor: 'pointer'
        });

        element.on('mousedown', function(event) {
          console.debug("in"); // This line is printed, but the lines below doesn't apply correctly
          event.preventDefault();
          startX = event.pageX - x;
          startY = event.pageY - y;
          $document.on('mousemove', mousemove);
          $document.on('mouseup', mouseup);
        });

        function mousemove(event) {
          y = event.pageY - startY;
          x = event.pageX - startX;
          element.css({
            top: y + 'px',
            left:  x + 'px'
          });
        }

        function mouseup() {
          $document.off('mousemove', mousemove);
          $document.off('mouseup', mouseup);
        }
      };
    });
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Elfayer/f2ognrxe/2/)

It should directly drag the box after it is created, but it's not.

I'm probably not using it correctly, what am I missing ?

Comment: You're missing [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element): "`triggerHandler()` - Passes a dummy event object to handlers". And, [indeed](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/jqLite.js#L957)…

Comment: That's what I thought, but I didn't find another way to do call the event. Also, it's weird because it is getting in the event.

Comment: Is there a way to "extract" the function `mousedown` of the `drag` directive and call it from `boxCreator` directive ?

Answer (score 1):

The `event` passed in from the `triggerHandler` call is not a real event. It has `preventDefault` and `stopPropogation` as methods that are no-ops. It doesn't have anything else including the `pageY` to `pageX` attributes you are accessing.

Here's a fiddle forked form your example that does at least get the  element position when the `triggerHandler` method is called: http://jsfiddle.net/bonza_labs/ft1rm8v9/1/

(get element position code from here: http://cvmlrobotics.blogspot.com/2013/03/angularjs-get-element-offset-position.html)

I don't think this is working as you expect (i.e. the box is created but doesn't "stick" to the mouse immediately)

— UPDATE —

heres fiddle that has the element listen to the mouse move event (line 63): http://jsfiddle.net/bonza_labs/ft1rm8v9/2/

It sticks to the cursor as long as it doesn't stray from the element, but does reveal there are details in the logic to work out still like, how does sticky box (i.e. following cursor on creation but w/o `mousedown` event) stop following as there isn't going to be a `mouseup`?

Comment: "I don't think this is working as you expect (i.e. the box is created but doesn't "stick" to the mouse immediately)" Yes, that's the behavior I'm trying to get.

Comment: Damn, thought I had a useful fiddle link there for you, but it's the same one you gave, not the version with my changes. Grrr.